# Array was out of bounds

Tags: c#, arrays

```
byte b = 0;
foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
{
    if (x is PictureBox)
    {
        x.Tag = saylar[b].ToString();
        b++;
    }
}
```

I am getting error saying that array was out of bounds, why is that? It works perfectly fine on my friend's C#.

Comment: `int[] saylar = new int[32];`

Comment: Either you check the the `b` value like `if (b<32) { x.Tag = saylar[b].ToString(); b++;}` or use `Generic List` or `Array List` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, appreciate your help! I fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error because `saylar[b]` is being pointed to an index that is out of the array's bounds.

Put a breakpoint on this line:
`x.Tag = saylar[b].ToString();`
and then watch the result as the code runs.

You haven't shown us what `saylar` is, but this is your problem.

Hope it helps!

Comment: You're correct sir. I made saylar an array of 36 elements and that fixed the problem! :-)